# Replacing a specific number of elements in one list with elements from another list

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice

I had a question regarding list operations.

Let's say I had the following two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and

```
b = [7,8,9]
```

If I was to input `a` as a value for one parameter within a function, and `b` as the second input within a function. How could I use indexing and slicing to have the elements in list `b` substitute (in this case) the values `[4,5,6]` so that the output would look like this:

Answer returned:

```
[1,2,3,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Is the operation you're describing a replacement of `a`'s suffix with `b`? If that's the case, is `b` always the same size as or smaller than `a`?

Comment: It is a partial replacement of the elements in list [a] based on the # of elements in list [b]. Does that help?

Comment: Well, you got your answer now, so whatever, but the replacement of a list by a list can be done in a multitude of ways, so, there was not enough information in your post to answer without guessing.

Answer (score -1):

lets say x is the length of b
use slicing to remove the last x values of a.
than add b to a.

```
def put_in(a,b):
    a = a[:len(a)-len(b)]
    a = a+b
    return a
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting so what you've done is taken the length of the first list and subtracted it by the length of the second, and then concatenated them? I am quite new to python, how is it that the local variable 'a' can be reassigned twice?

Comment: @MarkDonovan yes, a local variable a can be reassigned infinite number of times. It can be assigned to another functions or (hashmaps or dictionaries in python) or anything. A python variable is like a pointer in C/C++ that points to some data. It can point to any data that you specify.

Comment: pretty much i've sliced the original array "a" from its first index to the index of len(a)-len(b) which means i removed exactly len(b) elements because the length of a is len(a). after i removed len(b) elements from "a" i added the array b to the new sliced "a" array and put it again in a.  you can reassign "a" as much as you want you just have to keep track of what its currently holding. if you are new to python i suggest to not reassign varibles like i did in this example but create a new varible every time you want to save a sliced array, sum of numbers, etc.

Comment: Thank you to the both of you, Albin and Rozem. I believe I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how local variables worked within python.